# How to correctly expect the appearance of 'Select list'?

Tags: javascript

I need to press programmatically on button1, after pressing select list will appear and then on this select list i need to click on button2.
id of button1 is `#mx899`, but on the web page i'm working on, you cannot use command for clicking, like `document.querySelector('#mx899').click();`, it does not work. You can call function `sendEvent('click', 'mx899', '');` for clicking on button1, for clicking button2 you can call function `sendEvent('click', 'mx3481[R:2]', '');`
How to call these commands sequentially and alternately with one script?
How to correctly expect the appearance of 'Select list'?

```
sendEvent('click', 'mx899', '');
```

```
sendEvent('click', 'mx3481[R:2]', 'ev');
```

I tried to use Promise + async/await, but second click does not work,
I think my code lacks a check for waiting to appear 'Select list'

```
async function b()
{
    
    function f1()
    {
        return new Promise(resolve => 
        {
            resolve(sendEvent('click', 'mx899', ''));
        })
    }

    function f2()
    {
        return new Promise(resolve => 
        {
            resolve(sendEvent('click', 'mx3481[R:2]', ''));
        })
    }

    async function myf()
    {
        let res1 = await f1();  
        let res2 = await f2();
        return [res1,res2];
    }
    return myf();
}
b();
```

Comment: I don't know why `querySelector` doesn't work, but my attempt would be creating a function that clicks button1, tests if list is availiable and if so, click the list and return true, otherwise return false. then i would try a timer of lets say 500ms that calls this function and cancels the timer when the function returned true.

Comment: a fully working example of the target page with your script would surely help...

Comment: Don't have too much experience with await, but my guess here would be that the main function `b()` is async. You have `return myf()` which `await`s each function, but you're not awaiting the return of `myf()`. Logically, I think the main function just proceeds before `myf()` actually returned anything because of this.

Comment: @Michael, could you please write an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have the code of the html form and I dont know why `querySelector` or `getElementById` are not availiable to you, I can only provide an approach and not a running solution. Buy you might adjust it towards your environment.

```
function performActions() {
    let element1 = document.getElementById('mx899'); // get the button element
    element1.click(); // send the click event to the button

    let handle = window.setInterval(function() { // create a timer...
        let element2 = document.getElementById('mx3481[R:2]'); // try to get the list element
        if (!element2) return; // When the list element is not found, return and try on next timer iteration
        element2.click(); // list element is found, send click event
        window.clearInterval(handle); // stop the timer
    }, 500); // ...that triggers every 500ms
}
```

This code is **NOT** tested since I dont have the HTML code of the form!